# What is the most efficient way to pass multiple unknown number of parameters to the IN clause for a select query?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

One of the main requirements is for the query to be not compiled repeatedly. So, we need to use a prepared statement as it will be called from a spring boot application.

something like:
`select * from table where form_id in (?)`

I want to replace ? with a list that I will get from another service.
I am using Oracle JDBC driver.

I tried using connection.createArrayOf(..) but this doesn't work and give feature not supported error.

Comment: Use nested table types. For scalar datatypes there are predefined ODCI types: `sys.odci<datatype>list`. https://dbfiddle.uk/euHD4KDz

Answer (score 1):

You have to unwrap your connection to have an OracleConnection and call createARRAY, which requires to pass the SQL type of the array: e.g. CREATE TYPE  STRING_TAB IS TYPE OF VARCHAR2(...), then you pass "STRING_TAB", and in that case the second parameter will be a String[], and the IN expression on the SQL statement should be "IN(SELECT * FROM TABLE(?))".
You may also use SYS.ODCIxxx types.
You assign the parameter using stmt.setArray().